# google tag manager issue

Tags: wordpress, analytics, google-tag-manager

On my website I had two tags, both Universal Analytics. Since I only need one, I deleted the one which I no longer needed. Now when I scan my site with Google Tag Assistant, it stills shows me the old tag which I had deleted. When I go to the website with the Google Tag Manager preview and debugger, it does not show the tag I deleted.

In summary:

Normally without the GTM previewer it shows the old tag even though I deleted it.

With the preview and debugger on, it doesn't show the deleted tag (which is what I want).

Comment: Assuming you have published the container, might try clearing your cache / website cache.

Comment: i deleted my browser cache, then through this plugin called w3 total cache i deleted the website cache too and still the same issue.  @Max

Comment: This is unusual, if you are happy to share the website link and note the Tags that should and should not fire  I can take a closer look at what is firing on the page and hopefully provide more insight.

Comment: The website is Dexport.nl and the tag that should not fire is UA-35101570-1 @Max

Comment: Since it is wordpress, there may be a plugin as well. I can see Yoast SEO, DuracellTomi Tag Manager which has GA as well. You may want to scan plugins for GA as well template files for direct embed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @Kevin please recheck your container? is it published now ?

I added your GTM (ALONE) to a local host file and it fired all tags including 2 GAs. So issue is not with the SITE.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to you i took a closer look at my container instead of my website ahah, it appeared i didnt publish my changes, my boss didnt give me admin rights so i never saw the "Publish" button on the right corner of my screen. Thanks for this. i cant mark it as the answer, but if you edit your answer ill make sure i mark it.